# How to send data from view to controller by pressing link in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a little time devoloping with Codeigniter.

I try to send an ID by pressing link from view because I want to edit a profile and I need the ID on the controller and then send it to the stored procedure.

This is the code on php

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($info as $item):?>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row"> <?php echo  $item['id'];?></td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><?php  echo anchor('c_controller/edit', $item['name']); ?> </td>
            <td><?php  echo anchor('c_controller/edit', $item['name']); ?> </td>
            <td></td>       
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

I need the ID to know the row on the DB and then update the table with those params. I don't know how to send the ID to the controller.
The stored procedure on SQL works alright

I hope you can help me.
thks.!!!

Comment: IS it possible to use a get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your markup is a bit confusing, why do you want 2 columns with the same link?

anyway, for your example, you need your variables to be part of the link :

```
<td><?php  echo anchor('c_controller/edit/'. $item['name'].'/'.$item['id'], $item['name']); ?> </td>
```

which generates something like that:

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.php/c_controller/edit/name/id
```

then in your c_controller function you can access these variables easily

```
function edit($name,$id){
    echo $name;
    echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Server side code example:
    $data = array(
                   'title' => $title,
                   'name' => $name,
                   'date' => $date
                );

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

You can also check this [How to create links in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863548/how-to-create-links-in-codeigniter)